# jQuery setInterval by 5 seconds and Increment by previous interval

Tags: jquery

I am displaying the jQuery modal after 5 seconds using `setInterval`. I want to increment the number of seconds by the previous interval value.

Let's say the page loads and the modal appears after 5 seconds,  next time modal should appear after 10 seconds (incremented interval by previous value 5+5), then 20 seconds, then 40 seconds, and so on...

I have the following Code, But only firing every 5 fixed seconds:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#ex1').modal();
    }, 5000);
  });
</script>
<style>
  .modal {
    max-width: 70% !important;
  }
</style>
<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <a href="https://example.com">
    <img alt="image" src="https://example.com/image.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I implement the above condition?

Comment: do you want to increase the interval time after the page reloads?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `setInterval()` is not the right tool. I'd go with `setTimeout()`, with an *[event](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)* that fires when the modal is closed and a ***global counter*** that doubles its value each time you close the previous modal.

```js
let counter = 5000;

function repeatTimeout(ms) {
  console.log('counter is: ' + ms);
  return setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ex1').modal();
    counter *= 2;
  }, ms);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let timer = repeatTimeout(counter);

  $('#ex1').on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('closed modal');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = repeatTimeout(counter);
  })
});
```

```css
.modal {
  max-width: 70% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />


<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <a href="https://example.com">
    <img alt="image" src="https://example.com/image.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for... Thank you.